# Write members of a structure using low level I/O function

Tags: c, file, structure, low-level

I want to write a program able to "save" user's data on a file (More or less is like a registration routine).

User's information (Username, Password and ID) are stored into a structure. Initialize the structure is not a problem, though when I try to write it on the file using write(), garbage chars are wrote on it. I am able to retrieve the id hex dumping the file, but the other two strings are gone...

This is the code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FPATH   "../usertab.txt"

struct user{
    unsigned int id;
    char *username;
    char *password;
};

unsigned getr_id(void){
    unsigned int rand_id;
    rand_id = (rand() % 999) + 1;
    while(!(rand_id > 127 && rand_id <= 999))
        rand_id = (rand() % 999) + 1;
    return rand_id;
}

struct user buffer;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
srand(time(0));

int fd;

if(argc == 3){
    buffer.id = getr_id();
    
    buffer.username = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer.username, argv[1]);
    
    buffer.password = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(argv[2]));
    strcpy(buffer.password, argv[2]);
    
    printf("[DEBUG]: %d %s %s.\n", buffer.id, buffer.username, buffer.password);
    
    if((fd = open(FPATH, O_WRONLY, 0)) != -1){
        printf("[DEBUG]: FILE SUCCESSFULLY OPENED.\n");
        if((write(fd, &buffer, sizeof(struct user)) == -1)
            printf("[ERROR]: While writing the file.\n");
        write(fd, "\n", 1);
     } 
   }
 }
```

Terminal:

```
$ gcc -g -o insert_user insert_user.c 
$ ./insert_user Username Password123
[DEBUG]: 793 Username Password123.
[DEBUG]: FILE SUCCESSFULLY OPENED.
$ cat ../usertab.txt 
�M�_U�M�_U
$ hexdump -C ../usertab.txt 
00000000  19 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  a0 02 4d db 5f 55 00 00  |..........M._U..|
00000010  c0 02 4d db 5f 55 00 00  0a                       |..M._U...|
00000019
```

As I said before 0x0319 = 793, which is the ID but the rest is almost gone. Is there any way to write a structure using Low Lever I/O? I **have also tried to write each argument singularly, but I always get the same result.** Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are only writing pointers to the (present location of the) data to file, not the data itself. Those addresses will be meaningless later. So your statement "User's information (Username, Password and ID) are stored into a structure" is incorrect. Only the ID is stored there, the rest is stored somewhere else.

Comment: BTW you are off-by-one with `malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(argv[1]))` and the other one. You should add 1 for the string terminator.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected memory allocation as you have said. Though my problem still remain: i cannot figure of how to print the contend of the structure on the file using write(). Any idea?

Comment: Never mind. I solved it. You said the what pointers were point to were on a different location, so I changed the pointers into fix arrays. This way I can write the whole structure on the file. Thanks anyway

Comment: BTW, most Unix systems should have `strdup` which does strlen+memcpy without the off-by-one bug @WeatherVane pointed out.  (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html says it's part of POSIX 2008.)  Since you're already using POSIX `write`, you might as well make life easier.  (Although that's only relevant if you're using pointer-based data structures at all, not fixed-size records with all the data inside the struct itself.)

Comment: For pointer data structures, you might want [`writev(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/writev.2.html) with an iovec.  With 0-terminated C strings, that's parseable again without including lengths.

Comment: @Francesco with fixed length arrays, you must be careful about buffer overflow. You could protect with `strncpy` but even that has a danger because it is not guaranteed to nul-terminate the string copied, and you should always explicitly write a terminator after using `strncpy` at the last buffer element, that is at say `buffer.username[userbuflen-1]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane So you are saying that the way I was doing was correct (of course with +1 to malloc) and I should find a way to  print the content of what the structure pointers are pointing to? (I apologise for been such doubtful, but I am still mastering the language)

Comment: I was saying that you must be careful about buffer overflow, and data input often isn't as simple as we would like it to be.